# How to filter out item from ordered dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, ordereddictionary

For the following list of ordered dictionary items,

```
{"HOTEL_SURVEY_LIST": [ {"room_type":"single","resource_index":3,"room_id":"room0","available_facilities":33,"availability":"yes"}, {"room_type":"single","resource_index":7,"room_id":"room0","available_facilities":17,"availability":"yes"}, {"room_type":"single","resource_index":0,"room_id":"room1","available_facilities":18,"availability":"yes"}{"room_type":"single","resource_index":1,"room_id":"room5","available_facilities":45, "availability":"no"}]}
```

how can we form the tuple data structure of form:

```
[(('room0', 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 17), ('room1', 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .... ('room5', 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) )]
```

with its corresponding 'room_id' and resource_index values.

```
room_type = "single";
room_id = "room0" to "room5";
resource_index = 0-7;
availability = "yes" or "no";
```

if room_type = "single" and availability = "yes", tuple data structure/pattern should of format:

```
[('room0', 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 17), ('room1', 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ... ('room5', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
```

if room_type = "single" and availability = "no", then data structure/pattern in the form of:

```
[('room5', 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Here, '[('room0', 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 17)] -> (room_id,  resource_index0, resource_index1, .... resource_index7)

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing comma in your `HOTEL_SURVEY_LIST`, but let's assume you have

```
HOTEL_SURVEY_LIST =  [
    {
      "room_type": "single",
      "resource_index": 3,
      "room_id": "room0",
      "available_facilities": 33,
      "availability": "yes"
    },
    {
      "room_type": "single",
      "resource_index": 7,
      "room_id": "room0",
      "available_facilities": 17,
      "availability": "yes"
    },
    {
      "room_type": "single",
      "resource_index": 0,
      "room_id": "room1",
      "available_facilities": 18,
      "availability": "yes"
    },
    {
      "room_type": "single",
      "resource_index": 1,
      "room_id": "room5",
      "available_facilities": 45,
      "availability": "no"
    }
  ]
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to aggregate `available_facilities` over unique room ID's by `resource_index` following the conditionals you mentioned, then you could write something like:

```
import numpy as np

output = np.zeros((6,9)).tolist() #Initializes 6 arrays of 9 elements.
for i, o in enumerate(output): # Assign room names upfront.
    o[0] = f"room{i}" # string formatting requires python 3.6 but you can easily substitute

for room_dict in HOTEL_SURVEY_LIST: #Loop through the rooms
    room_id = room_dict["room_id"]
    room_numerical_id = int(room_id[-1])
    resource_index = room_dict["resource_index"]
    available_facilities = room_dict["available_facilities"] #Declare all the needed fields
    if room_dict["room_type"] == "single": # based on the condition, assign facilities count based on resource index.
        if room_dict["availability"] == "yes": # TODO for you: make the distinction between yes and no as I don't see it
            output[room_numerical_id][resource_index+1] = available_facilities
        else:
            output[room_numerical_id][resource_index+1] = available_facilities


output = [tuple(l) for l in output] # Convert lists to tuple to match your output
```

Note that I intentionally made the two if statements equal because I don't really understand what should happen if the room availability is "no" from your example, as the output looks the same.

I wrote it with comments so probably I did not do it the fastest way but hopefully, it helps you understand it better.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mabergerx !!, i have taken reference above code and almost achieved my required output.

Comment: Glad I could help. Can you accept the answer then, please? :)